# How to unminify jssor slider library?

Tags: jquery, cdn, jssor

I need to do some changes in jssor slider library https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jssor-slider/27.5.0/jssor.slider.min.js , but not able to do as I can find only minified version.
I have already checked github issues related to that but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Is this what you are after?
https://www.jssor.com/download-jssor-slider-development-kit.html

Comment: This one is jssor development kit, which also includes minified jssor library. I am looking for the unminified version of library itself.

Comment: @Divya There are variety of tools to unminify the js file in the internet you can try any of those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this online tool

https://unminify.com/

Just copy and paste all the code in the 'Paste your code here' section and hit 'UNMINIFY' button

Comment: I know about the unminify thing but what I need is the actual codebase of jssor and not the unminified(converted) version of jssor.